# JRuby `gem install` hangs forever on Ubuntu (Digital Ocean)

Tags: ubuntu, jruby, digital-ocean

I'm trying to start the fresh installation of Ubuntu (tried all in the range of 12.04-15.10) with Oracle 8 JDK (also tried with OpenJDK 7) and JRuby > 9.0.0.0.

I'm using `rvm` (also tried `rbenv`) to get it. Once it's installed `gem install *` hangs on any gem forever. `ps` shows no CPU or memory usage so it looks like it does totally nothing.

Does anybody have a clue how to even debug such a thing? :(

P.S. Installing MRI works on the same machine so it clearly is not a network issue.

UPD: Checked the other PaaS providers. It's only a problem of Digital Ocean.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this exact issue, and found that JRuby was failing to install due to a lack of entropy in the PRNG. By installing `haveged` to provide additional entropy, the install completed successfully. Caveat: [You may be compromising your security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34523/is-it-appropriate-to-use-haveged-as-a-source-of-entropy-on-virtual-machines).

See also: [How to Setup Additional Entropy for Cloud Servers Using Haveged](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged)

Comment: I was able to install some software on DigitalOcean, but it would hang on service restarts, especially on booting. TIL haveged FTW. It's an issue with isolated VMs, so we might see more of this issue until the entropy pool is better managed.